# Process substitution - Node.js child_process

Tags: node.js, bash, pipe, child-process, process-substitution

I'm trying to run a child process to modify a file (in two steps) before reading the modified content from stdout.
I'm trying to do this by using process substitution which works perfectly in bash but not when i try it from node.

This is kind of, what the command looks like..

```
var p = exec('command2 <(capture /dev/stdout | command1 -i file -) -',
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
   console.log(stderr);
});
```

stderr prints:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What is the proper way of doing this in node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by putting the commands in a shell script and calling the script from the node child process.
I also needed to add the following to set bash in posix mode to allow process substitution:

```
set +o posix
```

There is probably a nicer way of doing this directly from within node but it did the job.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by bash running in posix mode when invoked as `/bin/sh`.

Invoking bash directly from `/bin/bash` avoids that:

```
child_process.execSync('diff <(curl a) <(curl b)', {shell: '/bin/bash'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `spawn` a `child_process` with bash substitution in Node by invoking the `sh` command with the `-c` flag.

The `sh` command uses your default bash interpreter, and the `-c` flag asks the interpreter to read commands from within the string, Ie: `$(echo $PATH)`. Additional flags are then passed to their normal positional references, such as: `$0`, `$1`, ect.

So an example might be:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const prg = 'sh',

    args = [
        '-c',
        'echo $($0 $1)',
        'ls', // $0
        '-la' // $1
    ],

    opts = {
        stdio: 'inherit'
    };

// Print a directory listing, Eg: 'ls -la'
const child = spawn(prg, args, opts);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have bash evaluate a command with `bash -c 'command'`. I've tested this and it works with process substitution and child_process.